# Probability that Ram wins a gold coin or a silver coin.

Tags: probability

Ram rolls a pair of fair dice. If the sum of the numbers shown on the upper faces is 5, 6, 10, 11
or 12 then Ram wins a gold coin. Otherwise, he rolls the pair of dice once again and wins a
silver coin if the sum of the numbers shown on the upper faces in the second throw is the same
as the sum of the numbers in the first throw. What is the probability that he wins a gold or a
silver coin?

What I did :

1. P(He wins a gold coin)= (No. of cases where sum is 5,6,10,11 or 12)/(Total no of cases) = $$\frac{4+5+3+2+1}{36}=\frac{15}{36}$$
2. P(He wins a silver coin) = (No. of cases where sum is 2,3,4,7,8,9)/(Total no of cases)=$$\frac{1}{36}*\frac{1}{36}+ \frac{2}{36}*\frac{2}{36} +\frac{3}{36}*\frac{3}{36} + \frac{6}{36}*\frac{6}{36} + \frac{5}{36}*\frac{5}{36} + \frac{4}{36}*\frac{4}{36} = \frac{91}{1296}$$

But the P(he wins a silver coin) is $\frac{91}{21*36}$.

Comment: "*answer to the second part*"  What is the "second part" you are talking about?  The problem statement you have written only contains a single question.  For what its worth, I do agree with your found value of $\frac{2}{36}\cdot\frac{2}{36}+\frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{1}{36}+\dots+\frac{4}{36}\cdot\frac{4}{36}$ for $\Pr(\text{silver})$ but maybe the value you cite from someone else's solution is really for something like $\Pr(\text{silver}\mid\text{not gold})$?

Comment: Note, $36\cdot 36 = 1296\neq 2196$

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. Yes, in the solution they have done $P$(silver | not gold) But I don't understand why.

Comment: "*But I don't understand why*"  Because so long as you do things correctly you can phrase the solution however you want.  There is nothing wrong with saying here $\Pr(\text{silver or gold}) = \Pr(\text{silver})+\Pr(\text{gold})$ like you were going to do since there is no overlap.  There is also nothing wrong with saying $\Pr(\text{silver or gold}) = \Pr(\text{gold})+\Pr(\text{silver | not gold})\Pr(\text{not gold})$.  Both are correct.  Perhaps they are in the habit of phrasing it that way for those problems where it is more useful.

Comment: The biggest difference is that $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ is typically not true (*only when $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$*), but $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B\mid A^c)\Pr(A^c)$ is always true.

Comment: ok yes, I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes, you have successfully calculated the probability that Ram wins a silver coin. The solution you are referring to has instead opted to calculate the probability that Ram wins a silver coin given that he did not win a gold coin. Why? I think it is because they want to calculate
$$
P(\text{win coin}) = P(\text{win coin} \mid \text{win gold})\cdot P(\text{win gold}) + P(\text{win coin}\mid \text{not win gold})\cdot P(\text{not win gold})
$$
where that final $P(\text{win coin}\mid \text{not win gold})$ is what they calculate as $\frac{91}{21\cdot 36}$.

However, it is not difficult to see that winning gold and winning silver are mutually exclusive, so we can instead do
$$
P(\text{win coin}) = P(\text{win gold}) + P(\text{win silver})
$$
and you are well on your way to finishing this calculation.